# I need to update the id along with the name and desc - SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am selecting the id using

```sql
SELECT SCRTY_RISK_AREA_UI_AREA_ID_SQ.nextval as\"riskAreaNo\" FROM DUAL
```

This sql query from the database.

Now I need to update the name and description of the already existing data along with the id

```sql
UPDATE SCRTY_RISK_AREA 
SET AREA_NAME= :areaName, AREA_DESC= :areaDesc,IS_ACTIVE='N' 
WHERE UI_AREA_ID = :uiareaId");
```

Am updating using the above query.

Can anybody help me how to insert or generate the new id. am new to sql not sure how to generate new id

I am not sure how to update along with the id since i generate the id using sequence

Comment: Please share us your table structure also provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting a new row, then

```
insert into scrty_risk_area (id, area_name) values 
(scrty_risk_area_ui_area_id_sq.nextval, :areaName);
```

If you're updating existing ID values (probably not a good idea, especially if it is a primary key, not to mention if it is referenced by some foreign keys):

```
update scrty_risk_area set
  id = scrty_risk_area_ui_area_id_sq.nextval;
```

Comment: The update statement probably needs a where clause!

Comment: Maybe, @Boneist. Maybe column is empty so the whole table should be updated. Or it should be *resequenced* (the whole table again). Or, maybe only empty values should be populated (so WHERE would be used). Can't tell, as question doesn't contain that info. But yes - you might be right, I agree.